# Selenium Click on data-id C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I have this:

```
<a data-id="6948" class="klasax" href="show.aspx?xid=....;" title="Test">Test</a>
```

I trying to click based on `data-id="6948"`

My code:

```
 IWebElement cl = driver.FindElement(By.Id("6948");
 cl.Click();
```

Clearly problem is on `data-id` How I can click on it based on data-id ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a CSS selector, such as:

```
By.CssSelector("[data-id='6948']")
```

Answer (score 2):

`data-id` is not `id`, you can't find it using `By.Id` selector. You can use `CssSelector`

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[data-id='6948']"));
```

Or `ClassName`

```
driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("klasax"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `xpath`:

```
driver.FindElement(By.xpath('//a[@data-id="6948"]'));
```

Comment: This method is a last resort. When selecting using xpath we make the code brittle every small change will break our tests